# Enterprise Architect crashes on Database Compare

Tags: crash, enterprise-architect

So the situation is as follows: 
I have got online repo for EA project containing schema for database.

I also have this Oracle database, lets say host.cz:port/TESTDB. 
<< This database is currently in use and works fine. It does contain some more tables (mostly backups) compared to EAREPO schema.

Now I would like to run a database compare function of Enterprise Architect. So far I did following:

1. Downloaded and installed ODBC driver for Oracle
2. Modified registry entry so that the driver is included
3. Ran odbcad32.exe, found the driver, created User DSN using the oracle driver
4. Tested the connection - No error.

Now I logged Enterprise Architect, went to Database builder and called "Show differences" against the DNS I created before (step 3).

EA starts spinning the wheel and goes into "Not Responding" mode and remains so until killed (tried up to 15 minutes)

There is ~30 tables in the DB so it should not be that complex task...

My coworker has same problem, so I guess it is not problem in configuration on my station.

My PC also has i7 4800MQ processor and 16GB of RAM so resource shortage seems unlikely as well. The internet connection is also stable.

I currently ran out of ideas, so I would appreciate if you could point me in directions I should check out to make EA running as necessary.

Comment: I don't know this by myself, but on Sparx' forum there are a couple of people complaining about Oracle. You should cross post there in the hope to get someone who's actually using Oracle. Or (from what I understood) use anything else than Oracle.